# How would I add a method to this class that would be used to display info?

Tags: class, oop, pseudocode

I've put together this class so far but the last required step is to add a method that will display all of the practical info (I.E. the size, style and color) to the class itself.

I would typically just do this by setting up and calling a module outside of the class but for this project I am not aloud to do so.

Here's what I've got so far (I don't have the module main or any other modules set up just yet as I am hung up on this particular issue):

```
Class Sweater

Private Real sweaterSize
Private String sweaterStyle
Private String sweaterColor

Public Module Sweater()
    Set sweaterSize = 0
    Set sweaterStyle = " "
    Set sweaterColor = " "
End Module

Public Module Sweater(Real newSweaterSize, String newSweaterStyle, String 
newSweaterColor)
    Set sweaterSize = newSweaterSize
    Set sweaterStyle = newSweaterStyle
    Set sweaterColor = newSweaterColor
End Module

Public Module setSweaterSize(Real newSweatersize)
    Set sweaterSize = newSweaterSize
End Module

Public Function Real getSweatersize()
    Return sweaterSize
End Function

Public Module setSweaterStyle (String newSweaterStyle)
    set sweaterStyle = newSweaterStyle
End Module

Public Function String getSweaterStyle()
    Return sweaterStyle
End Function

Public Module setSweaterColor (String newSweaterColor)
    set sweaterColor = newSweaterColor
End Module

Public Function String getSweaterColor()
    Return sweaterColor
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to create another public function inside the class that calls your accessor methods or the variables themselves. For example

```
Public Function null display()
  Display getSweaterSize()
  Display getSweaterStyle()
  Display getSweaterColor()
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldnt that cause an error considering it isn't returning anything?

Comment: Oh yes sorry about that, you can make the function return type null.